# Passing on procedure pointers in gfortran leads to segfault

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I have a procedure pointer that I need to pass on a few functions down and it crashes when compiling with gfortran (but not with ifort). Here is a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```
module mod1

    abstract interface
        function f(x)
            double precision f
            double precision, intent(in) :: x
        end function f
    end interface

contains

    subroutine printme(g)
        procedure(f), pointer, intent(in) :: g
        write(*,*) g(1d0), g(2d0), g(3d0)
    end subroutine printme

    subroutine printme2(g)
        procedure(f), pointer, intent(in) :: g
        call printme(g)
    end subroutine printme2

end module mod1


program test

    use mod1

    procedure(f), pointer :: pg

    pg => g
    call printme2(pg)

contains 

    function g(x)
        double precision g
        double precision, intent(in) :: x
        g = x**2
        return
    end function g

end program test
```

Obviously in my program, my version of "printme2" does a little more than just that, but you get the point. It calls another routine lots of times and passes on the procedure pointer every single time. Now with the Intel compiler this works as expected:

```
$ ifort segfault.f90 && ./a.out
1.00000000000000        4.00000000000000        9.00000000000000
```

However, with gfortran (v4.4.5-8):

```
$ gfortran segfault.f90 && ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

Note that it works if I replace `printme2` with `printme` in the test program. 
Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong and how do I make it right?

Comment: I don't have GCC 4.4.5 around but your code compiles and works fine with `gfortran` 4.5.3, 4.6.1 and 4.7.0 and doesn't compile at all with 4.3.4. I would say you hit a bug or something not implemented right in 4.4.5. You can peek at the assembly output but you'd better just upgrade the compiler.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask our admin for an upgrade. Thanks for testing!

Comment: Note that allowing internal procedures as the *proc-target* of a procedure pointer assignment is a feature from the Fortran 2008 standard.

Comment: I tested also, it works fine with Gfortran 4.6.3 which is a stable version.